# Difference between UpdateView and BaseUpdateView - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

My Doubt is: Difference between `UpdateView` and `BaseUpdateView` and how to use them

I have tried to find information on the subject, but it is not much, so I have the doubt how to use exactly the `BaseUpdateView` view and similar views.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Did you check [BaseUpdateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/BaseUpdateView/) vs. [UpdateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/)? The _Ancestors_ are describing the difference.

Comment: and how should it be used? (BaseUpdateView)

Comment: You should not use BaseUpdateView unless you need to inherit from it to create a custom UpdateView class to later create your views with you new class. Always you need to create a update view use `UpdateView` as the docs say [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Comment: And when creating an object through a form that would be in a template redermised by a ListView view, would it be worth using a BaseCreateView? and I only send the data by POST, since that form would put it in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
UpdateView:
class django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView
    A view that displays a form for editing an existing object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving changes to the object. This uses a form automatically generated from the object’s model class (unless a form class is manually specified).
This view inherits methods and attributes from the following views:

django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin
django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin
django.views.generic.edit.BaseUpdateView
django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin
django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin
django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin
django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView
django.views.generic.base.View
Attributes

template_name_suffix
The UpdateView page displayed to a GET request uses a template_name_suffix of '_form'. For example, changing this attribute to '_update_form' for a view updating objects for the example Author model would cause the default template_name to be 'myapp/author_update_form.html'.

object:
When using UpdateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being updated.

Example myapp/views.py:

from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

Example myapp/author_update_form.html:

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

BaseUpdateView:
UpdateView already inherits the methods and attributes of BaseUpdateView
therefore, we do not need to use BaseUpdateView when using updateview. UpdateView will already be performing operations that BaseUptadeView will do
```